# Scanner asking more strings that expected

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to take string in input using Scanner.
But it asks me more strings that expected: shouldn't with this code ask 5 strings?

```
public void go()
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    String temp=new String();
    Integer i=new Integer(0);
    while(sc.hasNextLine() && i<5)
    {
        temp=sc.nextLine();
        list.add(list.size(),temp);
        i++;
    }
}
```

If I try to run it it asks me 6 strings before the console stops to take input.
But i at the beginning is zero, it gets incremented 5 times before becoming 5.
So why it also remain in while when i is 5?

Solved: Both methods solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `i == 5` still a `sc.HasNextLine()` is called. Repair:

```
while (i < 5 && sc.hasNextLine())
```

P.S. do `int i = 0;`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If i reaches 5, i < 5 will be false and the while loop end before calling sc.hasNextLine(). Already sc.hasNextLine does the reading if called.

Answer (score 4):

You have a misunderstanding on your code's execution.
It asks you 6 strings but adds 5 of them to the list.
The reason it asks you one more string is that, `sc.hasNextLine()` is executed, it's evaluated to `true`, so you see the console is expecting you to enter something, but then 2nd part of the loop condition comes: `i<5`, this is evaluated to `false` so the loop body is skipped and you have 5 strings in your list. You can see these in action by debugging your code in Eclipse or Netbeans or another Java IDE.

Just for convenience simplify your loop. Remove `sc.hasNextLine()` from loop condition.

```
while( i < 5 )
{
   temp=sc.nextLine();
   list.add(list.size(),temp);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: There's the solution, 1+. Even better though: use a for loop. That's what they're for.